# Create Task Schedule that run task after one is finished

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

Currently I have a task that run every 5 minute. 
what I want is to have that task rerun every time it is completed with 1 minute delay.

what I have in mind is to create multiple task, task A and task B. task B will run after task A complete and vice versa. But not sure how to execute that.

Comment: Why don't you add them as different actions of a single task? This way, the second one starts when the first one is finished. The delay can be a part of the first action.

Comment: I see so I combined everything, and add loop in the program with the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for my situation. what I do is create loop for task A to run followed by task B with delay in between.